# How to make sure stdout writes to a file when using Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

I have a listener that says "waiting for messages..." and then runs forever waiting for messages from all sorts of programs to pass to a responder. All of this works fine when I run it from the command line, but now I want to automate it so I don't have to start all my programs separately.

I started out by just trying to get my listener to start, but it doesn't print out the "waiting for messages..." message, or anything at all, when I try to route stdout to a file.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('listenerOutput', 'w') as outfile:
    Popen(["python", "listener.py"], stdout = outfile)
```

All the questions I've read so far seem to be more complex than this, but I can't even seem to make this part work. Presumably, any print statements in listener.py would show up in outfile, correct? But all I get is an empty 'listenerOutput' file. Is there some extra step to make it write to the file, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you add a `> listenerOutput` when you're using `Popen`?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense - he'd also need to set shell=True, but it also won't help. His stdout trick is correct. Not waiting for it to complete is the problem.

Comment: I ended up not being able to figure it out. In fact, the moment I do this in the command line:
    `python listener.py > listener_out &`
it doesn't write to anything! I still don't know why, so instead I used python's logging class in my listener to record everything and that works. And instead of using python to launch subprocesses, I used a bash script to make things simple. Still, if anyone has an idea on what went wrong, I'm all ears :]

Answer (score 1):

`Popen` does not block, so it returns as soon as the subprocess begins. Being the last line of the `with` statement, the context manager immediately closes the output file, which prevents `listener.py` from writing to it.

(Update: the child still has its own open file descriptor after the `with` statement exits. Exactly *why* the child's output isn't being written to the file isn't clear, but it's likely that it is somehow exiting prematurely.)

Either wait for the process to complete:

```
with open('listenerOutput', 'w') as outfile:
    Popen(["python", "listener.py"], stdout = outfile).wait()
```

or skip the `with` statement and close the file manually later.

```
fh = open('listenerOutput', 'w')
p = Popen(..., stdout=fh)
# Do some other stuff in the meantime.
p.wait()
fh.close()
```

Comment: I agree with the solution, but not so much the cause. The with clause closes the file for the parent but not for the child. I suspect that the parent process exits which kills its child before it writes.

Comment: That could be, but I'm not sure how `subprocess` actually works. Does it pass a file descriptor to the child, or does it simply open a pipe which the child writes to, and the `Popen` process reads from the pipe and writes to the open file object?

Comment: It passes a file descriptor to the child which means there are 2 open file descriptors to the file. Its mostly harmless unless you are pipelining multiple commands but you could close it in the parent immediately without harm.

Comment: You're right about the file descriptor being passed; however, simply exiting the parent does not cause the child to be killed (although there may be some other way the child is being terminated prematurely).

Comment: Yeah, your right... i should have thought about that more. Perhaps listener.py is running the the background and will eventually write the file when its internal buffers finally fill enough.

Comment: Ok, I tried skipping the with statement and closing the file manually, and it does write to the file! However, it only does so after I ctrl+c out of the program. The reason I'm doing Popen is so that the listener will run in the background, preferably forever, and write to the file as it runs. I think because the parent is the one in charge of opening and closing, it stays running because the child isn't done yet (and the child isn't supposed to finish up any time soon).

Answer (score 0):

The `listener` script is probably not flushing `stdout`. The console probably has auto-flush so you didn't notice before.

Putting `sys.stdout.flush()` after your `write`/`print` in `listener.py` will flush the output.

Tested with a similar `Popen` setup and a script that printed a message and then waited 5 seconds. Message appeared in the file after 5 seconds without flush, immediately with.

Comment: This is useful if the data really does need to get to the file immediately. Generally, its best to let the program buffer and flush on its own for better performance.